# Character in a string formation

Tags: r, rselenium

I use Rselenium and I use javascript queries.

The query in javascript is this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul#test div.mytext')[1].innerText.split('\n').filter(x => x).join('???')
```

When I try to run it in RSelenium code I use this:

```
remDr$executeScript('return document.querySelectorAll(\'ul#test div.mytext\')[ 1 ].innerText.split(\'//\n\').filter(x => x).join(\'???\')', args = list("dummy"))
```

However I receive an error and I belive it is due to `\n` character

How can I write it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for delimiting the code you want to run when it also contains single quotes.  Since there are no double quotes in the expression, try:

```
remDr$executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll(\'ul#test div.mytext\')[ 1 ].innerText.split(\'//\n\').filter(x => x).join(\'???\')", args = list("dummy"))
```